# Vertically aligning an image with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this little game for my kid to play with that every time he hits a key or clicks the mouse that the screen will generate a random colour and letter and display it to him. I have now decided to make it add animal flash cards as well. The problem is I can't seem to get the damned images to vertically align in the div box that's floating in the middle. Any ideas?

Live version minus the animals can be viewed here if you need some idea as to what I'm going on about - http://64-b.it

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var alphabet = new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");
    function getNum() {
        return "#" + Math.round(Math.random() * (16777215 - 0) + 0).toString(16);
    }
    function getLetter() {
        var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (101 - 0) + 0);
        if(ranNum < 61){
            return alphabet[ranNum];
        }else{
            return "<img src='images/1.jpg' width='480px' />";
        }
    }

    function doStuff(){
        document.bgColor=getNum();
        document.getElementById('middle').innerHTML=getLetter();
    }

    $(window).on('click touchstart', function(){
        doStuff();
    });

    $(window).keydown(function(){
        doStuff();
    });

  </script>
  <body oncontextmenu="return false">
    <div id="middle">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#middle {
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: consolas;
    font-size: 500px;
    border: solid 20px black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 590px;
    margin-top: -295px;
    width: 490px;
    margin-left: -245px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` you can just set a `line-height equal` to the div's height, that will center text (single-line) and images vertically

Comment: Nah doesn't work, tried that already. Just tried it again to make sure i've not lost my mind, it doesn't work.

Comment: On a JSFiddle it looks like it's supposed to look, but running it with the exact same code normally it doesn't work properly - http://jsfiddle.net/euG2r/

Comment: This was correct, needed to be specified as XHTML Strict. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score -1):

What if you set something like this to cheat it:

```
#middle img {
 position: relative;
 top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Urr, no you can't, not if you want it to be vertically and horizontally aligned so that no matter what resolution or zoom value it's bang centre of the screen.

Comment: Aha, I see, misunderstood.

Comment: I've figured it out, was simple - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> :P

Comment: Ha just changing doc type? Nice!